# Getting an infinite loop with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|static|uploads)(/.*)?$
RewriteRule ^admin(/.*)?$ /index.php/admin$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/.*)?$ /index.php/webshops$2?dealer=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Even though I exclude `index.php` in the rewrite condition, I still get the following error:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable always starts with a `/`, so you need to include that in your regex:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php|robots\.txt|static|uploads)(/.*)?$
```

Comment: @not-rightfold Sorry, you need to add the condition before both of your rules. The `RewriteCond` directive is only applied to the immediately following `RewriteRule`